# colorlinks option of hyperref with TeXnicCenter doesn't work

Tags: hyperref, color, miktex, texniccenter

I am new to the `hyperref` package. When I am not using the `colorlinks` option, it works well. (Loading other options like `pdfborder` presents no problem.) But, once I load the `colorlinks` option, the result becomes extremely bewildering: no errors, no warnings, and **no output**! :-(

Here are two pieces of sample code (the simplest ones):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

The result: **0 error(s), 0 warning(s), 0 Bad Boxes(s), 0 page(s)**
(I don't know how to copy and paste the console output. Anyone knows how to do that?)

What's wrong with `colorlinks`?

**Problem solved:**
As what @Ulrike commented, it was TeXnicCenter blocking the on-the-fly installation of color package. I switched to TeXworks, then the package is automatically installed. Now the output is fine.

Comment: Which version of `hyperref` do you use? `hyperref` has the option `allcolors`.

Comment: With colorlinks hyperref will try to load the color package (and some other files), so my guess is the files aren't yet installed and that (again) texniccenter is blocking the on-the-fly installation. Compile in texworks or on the command line.

Comment: Adding to what @Ulrike said: It's not necessary to switch over to TeXworks, I'd suggest to change the package installation in the MiKTeX Settings to on-the-fly. This way, TeXnicCenter will work just fine. (Btw, your MWE compiles just fine for me with TXC and MiKTeX, so it's most likely got something to do with installed packages and/or package versions.)